# Декоратор для метода класса с ссылкой на объект класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть некий класс, скажем, `MyClass`. Я хочу сделать декоратор для метода этого класса (и некоторых других). В декораторе мне хотелось бы иметь ссылку на объект этого класса.

В `Python 2` была замечательная функция `inspect.getargspec`, которая сейчас (в `Pyton 3`) является `deprecated`.

Покапавшись в докуменации я нашел лишь способ узнать есть ли аргумент `self` в функции или нет.

***Вот пример такого поиска:***

```
import inspect


def get_reference_by_method(f):
    all_args_of_method = inspect.signature(f).parameters
    if 'self' in all_args_of_method:
        print("I've found self!")
    else:
        raise Exception('It is not a class method')
    return None # I don't know how to get a reference on self 


def super_decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = get_reference_by_method(f)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class MyClass:

    @super_decorator
    def decorating_method(self):
        print('Hello from the decorating method')

MyClass().decorating_method()
```

***Вывод в консоль:***

```
I've found self!
Hello from the decorated method
```

Не могу понять, что мне надо сделать, чтобы получить этот `self`.

Comment: Не по теме вопроса: проверка так себе, так как `def foo(bar, baz, self=None)` тоже является вполне валидным методом класса, а объект этого класса будет передан в `bar`

Comment: @andreymal да, согласен. С такой проверкой я не уйду дальше своего проекта, в котором везде `self`. Но есть ли какие-нибудь более правильные альтерантивы ? Я пока ничего такого найти не могу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` — это просто первый аргумент метода:

```
import functools

def print_self_decorator(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self)
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Пример:

```
class C:
    @print_self_decorator
    def method(self):
        print(C.method.__name__)

C().method()
```

Результат:

```
<__main__.C object at 0x...>
method
```

Comment: это не отвечает на вопрос: узнать есть ли аргумент self в функции? например @staticmethod

Comment: @vadimvaduxa: потому что такой вопрос не стоял—посмотрите на заголовок ("пытаться определить есть ли self в функции" это была неудачная попытка решения в вопросе). Очевидно, что декоратор для методов экземпляра предназначен. В \@staticmethod нет self, нечего искать.

Answer (score 1):

```
from inspect import getmembers, ismethod

def super_decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        if args:
            method = getmembers(args[0], ismethod)
            print('\n', method or type(f))

            if method:
                self = args[0]

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class MyClass:
    @super_decorator
    def decorating_method(self):
        print('Hello from the decorating method')

@super_decorator
def decorating_method(self):
    print('Hello from the decorating method')

MyClass().decorating_method()
decorating_method(2)
```

out:

```
 [('decorating_method', <bound method MyClass.wrapper of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x02999970>>)]
Hello from the decorating method

 <class 'function'>
Hello from the decorating method
```

Comment: Но мне надо вытащить ссылку на объект класса, а не на метод этого объекта.

Comment: очевидно что это args[0]

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать такой вариант. Работать не будет в том случае, если имя функции будет совпадать с одним из методов в первом аргументе.

```
def super_decorator(f):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if args and hasattr(args[0].__class__, f.__name__):
            print("method")
        else:
            print("function")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class MyClass:

    @super_decorator
    def decorating_method(self):
        print('Hello from the decorating method')


@super_decorator
def test(value):
    print("From function", value)


MyClass().decorating_method()

test([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Можно сократить до `if args and hasattr(args[0].__class__, f.__name__)`

Comment: Да верное замечание.